# Android Simple Camera Activity

Tags: java, android, camera, android-manifest, android-camera

I'm simply trying to automate a fixed phone to take pictures. (I don't want a preview in UI, just need the image saved to SD card).  I get a "Failed to connect to camera service" at the line where I call `camera.open()`.  Most examples implement a callback with surfaces, but that is unneccessary.  What am I doing wrong?  I have the correct permission in my manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"></uses-permission>
```

This is the class I'm using, but something is clearly wrong!

```
public class SimpleCameraActivity extends Activity {

    Context mContext = this;

    Button takePicture;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        super.setContentView(R.layout.main);

        takePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePicture);

        takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });

    }

    public void takePicture() {
        Camera camera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.set("camera-id", 2);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.takePicture(null, rawCallback, null);
        camera.release();
    }

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera camera) {
            if (imageData != null) {
                saveImage(mContext, imageData, 100);
            }
        }
    };

    public void saveImage(Context mContext, byte[] imageData, int quality) {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath();
        filePath += "/image.jpg";

        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 5;

            Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                    imageData.length, options);

            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    fileOutputStream);

            myImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, bos);

            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ..Also, anybody have examples for doing the same thing with MediaRecorder (e.g. simply recording straight to SD card and not rendering preview to UI)?

Comment: In answer to my own comment, this may be of help later on to me: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/04/simple-exercise-of-video-capture-using.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't want a preview in UI

That is not supported. You must have "a preview in UI".

> Most examples implement a callback with surfaces, but that is unneccessary.

No, it is very necessary.

Comment: I meant unnecessary for me :)  Frankly, that stinks!

Comment: "that stinks" -- privacy advocates would disagree with your sentiment. The user needs to know that the camera is in operation. Now, I could certainly see other ways of accomplishing that end that might eliminate the need for a preview (e.g., mandatory `Notification`, as with `startForeground()`), but we don't have that yet.

Comment: While I do understand your point, I gave the application permissions to the camera; I'm waiving my rights!  Those advocates, always causing trouble :)  Also, I could see real-world use-cases for this with Android@Home -- I would love to see something like this in place for pub/sub (I'm trying to take pictures at a remote location).